# How to set permissions such that users can add, edit, and delete list/library items, but cannot edit web part pages or delete web part pages?

Tags: security

I need the ability for users to add, edit, and delete lists/libraries but not have the ability to edit web part pages or delete web part pages. I am boggled that the Edit Items permission allows for editing and deleting web part pages. The alternative I see at the moment is setting Read permissions across the entire site, and then setting specific permissions on each individual List/Library. The problem with this is that I have site templates, so the security does not remain in the site template (it inherits from the parent). Can someone clarify this for me? Or suggest what permission level I should use to accomplish my goal stated above? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your web part pages could be kept in a single library with specific permissions (all read only) on just that library.

Additionally: Web Part Pages are simply List Items in a Document Library.

Comment: Sometimes the simplest things in life are the hardest to figure out. Thanks.

Comment: Sometimes all you need is fresh eyes on a problem to see a different perspective :)